# why does the previous package/app name appears in the flutter app project name?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

i got a flutter app from someone and i have changed the app name and package name every where i can find, changed the names of the folders aswell in java and such directories from com.example.marcel to com.example.myapp but still my project is being displayed as myapp**[marcel]**
please see the image to see what i mean.

Here is the screenshot showing the [marcel] in the project
[image: Photo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a new project and import all data from this to your app and if you keep also is donset make any issue

Answer (score 0):

Done as follows in android studio:
You right click on the project name then select **Refactor** > **Rename** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfcUE.png)